# Use CloneZilla to backup disk2image (Primary Boot) without CD or USB Drive?

Tags: linux, debian, clonezilla

Since I won't be near the physical machine, I need to find a way to disk2image backup/restore the Primary Boot HDD in case I mess it up somehow.

How do you use CloneZilla to backup disk2image (Primary Boot) without using CD or USB drive?

Comment: mount you main disk as read only and use the best command ever : `cat /dev/yourdisk > /remote/file/system/backup.img` you can put also a zipper to reduce the load but that's the magic of unix knocking at your window, you can adapt every thing

Comment: You mean edit /etc/fstab to mount main disk as read-only, then use `cat` to backup disk img? Then how do I restore the img later after a disaster? (assuming I can at least boot into the messed up system)

Comment: `cat /your/file > /dev/yourdisk`

Comment: So after img backup, I revert the /etc/fstab back to original and reboot. When I try to restore the img, won't the cat command warn that /dev/sda is the partition I booted from and complain that there are locked system files?

Comment: Why do you want to modify the fast above. Just use mount with the correct options. You shouldn't use that technics anyway because you are obviously uncomfortable with that.

Comment: I will try it out on a test machine and see how it goes. Thanks.